# Error building R package mvtnorm on OSX

Tags: r, macos, fortran, clang, gfortran

When I install the `mvtnorm` package in R using `package.install("mvtnorm")`, I get this error:

```
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
/usr/local/bin/gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
/var/folders/_0/bvqq9l5d2ngg0stvkf53jrbr0000gn/T//ccxlxy4X.s:2601:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
/var/folders/_0/bvqq9l5d2ngg0stvkf53jrbr0000gn/T//ccxlxy4X.s:2614:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
```

I suspect the problem could be with the version of `clang` and `gfortran`, so I unlinked `gcc-5.3.0` and use `clang-3.6.0` and `gfortran 4.9.2` instead. The compiled version of gfortran is [obtained from this site](http://coudert.name/software.html).

This got me further, but I still see this warning:

```
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
/usr/local/bin/gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c mvtnorm-init.c -o mvtnorm-init.o
/usr/local/bin/gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c tvpack.f -o tvpack.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o mvtnorm.so C_FORTRAN_interface.o miwa.o mvt.o mvtnorm-init.o tvpack.o -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0/5.3.0 -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/5 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for _mvkbrv_: stack subq instruction is too different from dwarf stack size
```

What is the best way to build R packages that requires `gfortran`, on [homebrewed](http://brew.sh) GCC on OSX 10.10 and above?

Comment: Use tag fortran to get more attention (see the number of subscribers for fortran and gfortran).

Comment: if you google for the ld warning message you'll find something like https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/279914 try to add option "-Wl,-no_compact_unwind"